# conditional where in codeigniter : apply where if previous where satisfied

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to retrieve data from table using codeigniter.

doing something like that:

```
   ....
      $this->db->where('course_request.enrollment_policy !=', '2');
    //I want to write next statements something like:
    $this->db->if_where('course_request.enrollment_policy ', '3')
       then
    $this->db->where('course_request.status', '3'); 
else 
other codeigniter where_in
```

Hope you got my problem.
Looking for solution, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

who says it is not possible in CI?

```
$this->db->where('(CASE WHEN `course_request`.`enrollment_policy` = 3 THEN `course_request`.`status` =  "3" ELSE course_request.status="0" OR course_request.status = "3" END )' , NULL,FALSE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just paste this in your where :

```
AND (
    CASE 
    WHEN `course_request`.`enrollment_policy` = 3 
      THEN `course_request`.`status` =  '3' 
        ELSE 1=1
    END
    )
```

and give second param **NULL** , third param **FALSE**